# Can't connect to MDF file

Tags: c#, wpf, database-connection

I'm unable to connect to an existing MDF file using the following code:

```
conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;" +
    "Integrated Security=True;" +
    "AttachDbFilename=" + Path.GetFullPath("Database.mdf") + ";");
conn.Open();
```

I get the following error, no matter what I try:

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.)
```

Comment: It looks like your sql server instance may not be running.  Have you verified that the service is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is funny, I had the same issue not a long time ago. You said no matter what you try it is not ok. Still, you have a typo somewhere. Here is my older one:

```
public const string ssqlconnectionstring = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;" +
    @"AttachDbFilename=C:\MyFilePath\MyDBFile.mdf;" +
    @"Integrated Security=True;" +
    @"MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" +
    @"User Instance=False";
```

Also, you might use

```
"(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB";
```

instead of *\v11.0*. I had issues with it. If you encounter some version or compatibility problem, that could be it.

In addition, the "environment" changed a bit in my code, and use the DB as a project item for Entity Framework. This way Visual Studio generates the connection string. Here, I found it in a config file:

```
<Value Profile="(Default)">Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\MyFilePath\MyDBFile.mdf;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework</Value>
```